# How to get velocity.log file using log4j.properties file. i don't want to involve velocity.properties file

Tags: log4j, velocity

Now my velocity.log and velocity.log.1 are at `:installed software eclipse Kepler\eclipse-64\eclipse`

i don't know how these files are created here.

Answer (score 0):

By default, Velocity log files are created in the current working directory.

To change this behavior, you'll have to somehow configure Velocity. If you don't want to mess with `velocity.properties`, then you can configure Velocity using Java, as described in [this documentation section](http://velocity.apache.org/engine/releases/velocity-1.7/developer-guide.html#usinglog4jwithexistinglogger) which explains how to have Velocity log to an existing Log4j logger.

Comment: Thanks, but still the log files are created in the current working directory.

Comment: Need some more explanation

Comment: The documentation link I gave you only explains how to instruct Velocity to log to an existing Log4j logger. Do you already have a configured Log4j logger? Can you show us its configuration? Also, when you say that you need more explanations, what is it that you don't understand?

Comment: this is my log4j                                            log4j.category.VELOCITY=DEBUG, VEL

log4j.appender.VEL=org.apache.log4j.RollingFileAppender
log4j.appender.VEL.File=${logFileDir}/Velocity.log
log4j.appender.VEL.Append=true
log4j.appender.VEL.MaxFileSize=500KB
log4j.appender.VEL.MaxBackupIndex=3
log4j.appender.VEL.layout=org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout
log4j.appender.VEL.layout.ConversionPattern=%d - %m%n

Comment: /* first, get and initialize an engine */
    
    VelocityEngine ve = new VelocityEngine();
     
    ve.setProperty(RuntimeConstants.RUNTIME_LOG_LOGSYSTEM_CLASS, "org.apache.velocity.runtime.log.Log4JLogChute" );
        
    ve.setProperty( "runtime.log.logsystem.log4j.logger", "root" );

Comment: String sVelocityFilePath = m_rmFramework.getPluginManager()
      .getPlugin(PLUGIN_ID).getPluginPath()
      + File.separator + ANIMATION_DATA_CONFIG_FILE_PATH;
    File velocityFile = new File(sVelocityFilePath);
    ve.addProperty("resource.loader", "file");
    ve.addProperty("file.resource.loader.class",
      "org.apache.velocity.runtime.resource.loader.FileResourceLoader");
    ve.addProperty("file.resource.loader.path",
      velocityFile.getParent());
    ve.addProperty("file.resource.loader.cache", "true");
    ve.init();

Comment: i hope it will gives some idea to you.